# json_encode adds table name

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following code in my mySQL Table row "contacts":

```
{
    "contactList":
    [
        {
            "userId":"1062",
            "name":"Test User 1"
        },
        {
            "userId":"1063",
            "name":"Test User 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I encode the content json_encode adds the name of the table to the result:

```
{"contacts":"{"contactList": 
 [{"userId":"1062","name":"Test User 1"},{"userId":"1063","name":"Test User 2"}]
  }"}
```

Can anybody tell me how to avoid this or where's my mistake? I couldnt find any answer :(

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
...
    $last = mysql_query("SELECT contacts FROM users WHERE userId = 1000");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($last))
        $jsonEncode = (json_encode($row));
    $output = preg_replace('/\\\"/',"\"", $jsonEncode);
    print($output);
    mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: When you encode what exactly? If this is coming out in the JSON it means it is in the array you are supplying to json_encode.

Comment: If your column already contains JSON, why are you json_encoding it again? The preg_replace also doesn't make it valid. And you shouldn't do it in a loop anyway, as multiple concatenated JSON blobs aren't valid.

Comment: So should I just try to print the $row? Cause when I do so I didnt get a output or only "Array" Sorry I know this is really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($last))` for

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($last))
 $jsonEncode = json_encode($row['contacts']);
```

Comment: Hi & thans! When I do so the result is: {"0":"{"contactList": [{"userId":"1062","name": ...

Comment: Jeyyy :) it works! thanks a lot!!! I had no idea, that i can access the json that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that saved data is already json encoded and to get the output you just need to decode.

Change below line

```
$jsonEncode = json_decode($row['contacts']);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! But when I try so I get the following error: Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ...